# SQL - How to combine these three SQL queries?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to SQL and need help combining three SQL queries.

**Query 1**

```
SELECT max(level) level FROM tablename WHERE id = 1
```

The result of this is 3 in this example, this value will be used in query 2.

**Query 2**

```
SELECT max(run) run FROM tablename WHERE id = 1 AND level = 3;
```

The result of this is 1 in this example, this value will be used in query 3.

**Query 3**

```
SELECT levelpassed FROM tablename WHERE id = 1 AND level = 3 AND run = 1;
```

Here is the structure of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `level` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `run` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `cr` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `fr` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `dv` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `levelpassed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Here are the primary keys:

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`date`);
```

**I need to know all three values from the queries. The max level, max run and the levelpassed.**

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The combination of these three will not be more efficient than executing them in a separated way. Actually, in any DBMS engine I know you should not combine these since they have a different "where" clause.

Comment: Please do describe the need of it (in a use-case type of story) than someone might be able to help you. without it, it is hard (for me at least) to try and imagine a use-case for it

Comment: Is id/level/run unique, will the last query always return one row?

Comment: @PeterLang id + date will be unique. id + level + run is not unique. The last query should only return one row.

Comment: Could you just do a single `SELECT` ordered by `level DESC, run DESC` and use `LIMIT` to retrieve the first row?

Answer (score 0):

This is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename T
INNER JOIN (SELECT T2.id
             ,MAX(T2.level) AS [level]
           FROM tablename T2) TL ON TL.id = T.id
                                  AND TL.level = T.level
INNER JOIN (SELECT T3.id
             ,MAX(T3.run) AS [run]
           FROM tablename T3) TL ON TR.id = T.id
                                  AND TR.run = T.run
WHERE T.id = 1
```

Hope this will help you for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a result output by the query?

please try:

```
select levelpassed from tablename a where id = 1 and run = (select max(run) from tablename b where a.id = b.id) and level = (select max(level) from tablename c where a.id = c.id);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try querying like the following:

```
SELECT levelpassed ,
  (SELECT max(LEVEL) LEVEL
   FROM tablename
   WHERE id = 1) level,
  (SELECT max(run) run
   FROM tablename
   WHERE id = 1
     AND LEVEL = 3) run
FROM tablename
WHERE id = 1
  AND LEVEL =
    (SELECT max(LEVEL) LEVEL
     FROM tablename
     WHERE id = 1)
  AND run =
    (SELECT max(run) run
     FROM tablename
     WHERE id = 1
       AND LEVEL = 3);
```

Actually this is pretty inefficient, but it should do what you need.

Comment: This would only give me the value of levelpassed. I need to know all three values. Thank you.

Comment: @noc2spamツ `LEVEL = 3` should not be hardcoded, because the value of `LEVEL` is a result of **query 1**

Comment: @Karolis yeah I see that now. This is best implemented separately IMO.